# Android Studio "your cpu does not support vt-x or svm" After updating to windows 10 1903

Tags: virtualbox, cpu, motherboard, virtualization, android

2 weeks ago I updated to windows 10 1903 before that I was able to set up an emulator in Android Studio, after the update I get the error "your cpu does not support vt-x or svm". After looking it up I found out I have to enable virtualization in my motherboard. Went into the bios and to my surprise it was already on. Booted back into windows and tried with Hyper-V, no dice. I am at a complete loss. What am I supposed to do?

My specs are:

Motherboard: ASRock AB350M

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600